# Fonts skewed on top bar when using Radiance

Tags: unity, themes, fonts, radiance

The fonts are weird to look at and are surrounded by fuzziness (it's hard to see on these pictures):

[image: radiance font skewed]

When using the Ambiance theme this does not occur:

[image: ambiance fonts not skewed]

I've tried messing with hinting options in Ubuntu Tweak. It would seem that, when using ambiance, everything except the top bar is not affected. All fonts change visibly when I move from "maximum" to "no hinting" and vice versa, but the fonts on the top bar appear to stay the same.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem (on 12.04.3) and it turned out to be **a font antialiasing issue**. I switched it **from Rgba to Grayscale** (using **gnome-tweak-tool**, but Ubuntu Tweak will undoubtedly have an option for that as well) and the fuzzy colored edges went away. So far, I haven't been able to detect any adverse effect of switching this setting (i.e. noticeably ugly fonts elsewhere in the DE).

Oh, and you need to hover over/click on the top bar text labels for the change to take effect. Or at least I did :) Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the info. I'll submit this as a bug. It makes using 1/2 good default themes almost unbearable.

Comment: Good idea. I wonder whether it'll be fixed in 14.04 this April...

Comment: It has not been fixed.

Comment: This is still an issue in 14.04.